# How can I prevent stack build using nix from the command line?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to build a docker image of a Haskell application.

In my stack.yaml I have nix enabled with:

```
nix: 
  enable: true
```

When running 'stack build' in the docker container (that does not have nix) it errors with:

```
Downloading lts-13.5 build plan ...
Downloaded lts-13.5 build plan.
Executable named nix-shell not found on path:
```

Can I disable nix (some command line flag?) without having to modify the `stack.yaml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable nix on the command line using:

```
stack --no-nix build
```